# Pass jsondata in url as array

Tags: php

How to pass jsondata in URL in php, I searched and tried using http_build_query() it is passing like this

```
    http://abcd/xyz?id=12&name=mansfh
```

but I want URL to be like this

```
    http://abcd/xyz?jsondata={"id":"12","name":"mansfh"}
```

Please, someone, help me

Comment: there is no much changes with urlencode of java and php, see the below answer, it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with url encode, it works worth

```
<?php
$json_str = "{'id':'12','name':'mansfh'}";
$url_json = urlencode($json_str);
$url = "http://abcd/xyz?jsondata={$url_json}";

//to get the JSON again in http://abcd/xyz page

$json_str = urldecode($_GET['jsondata']);

?>
```

Comment: This is what i expected. Thank you Sathish Kumar D.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href= 'http://abcd/xyz?jsondata={"id":"12","name":"mansfh"}' target="_blanck">a</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eudgyj3u/